# Maximum log-likelihood from data histogram not data directly

Tags: statistics, wolfram-mathematica

I have a complicated theoretical Probability Density Function (PDF) that I define in mathematica and that depends on some parameters that I need to estimate from comparison with real data. From a big simulation done on a cluster and not my laptop I have acquired a lot of events (over 10^9).

The way I understand things, given that I know what the PDF is I 'just' need to sum the probability that those events appear for a given set of parameters and maximise this quantity by adjusting the parameters.

However, given the number of events I would rather work with something less computer-time consuming and work for example with something easily generated like an histogram of my data. But then how would my log-likelihood estimator work?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: You could sample from your data and compute the PDF from the sample.

Comment: I thought of that but I wondered how to correctly sample in order to accurately respect the "true" Pdf of my data, and then wouldn't I loose precision on the estimates since I would be reducing the number of events ?

Comment: Of course you loose precision, but by sampling randomly the chances are good that the estimation is representative. You could increase the certainty by sampling multiple times and using some kind of mean. Although you could still try to compute the PDF of all your data points and save it for later use. This might take a while (no idea how long but vectorizing should speed this up) but might be better in the long run.

Comment: Does [`EmpiricalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html) not do what you need?  It can be used as a distribution with all probability functions.

Comment: Not really because I have already generated the empiral PDF from my data. What I did in the end was fit the parameters of my theoretical PDF to the empirical one using NonLinearModelFit. I think I'll try doing a maximum likelihood on a subset of my data at least to compare the differences in the parameter best values and errors. 
Thanks a lot for your help =)